Reason for infinite solutions under perfect multicollinearity
I’m wondering why there would be infinite solutions (as opposed to none) for the normal equation $X’X\beta = X’y$ in least squares estimation when there are more variables than observations ($p>n$).
I’m trying to answer this from the viewpoint of vector spaces and adjoint operators, but I don’t know how to proceed.
Hints or direct answers would be appreciated!

This is an immediate and easy consequence of the basic dimension theorems of linear algebra.  The duplicates demonstrate the result in a variety of ways, including the methods you ask about.  BTW, the standard term for "perfect multicollinearity" is "collinear."
